# Create polygon symbology from attribute?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-10.3, color

I have shapefile with polygons and lines. There are attributes for: layer, lineweight, colour: Red, colour: Green, colour: Blue. (colour values are from 0-255).

Is there a way to read values from attributes, and assign colour and lineweight to polygons and/or lines? After that I would like to use the save layer option to save symbology.

I'm using ArcMap 10.3.

Comment: I really don't know why this is still missing. Searching the net, there are so many posts about that topic, so we must believe esri just does not want such a function in arcmap.

Comment: This would only be possible using ArcObjects.  I have never seen anyone post code for it.  The layer properties dialog and Python cannot do this at all.  This might be possible using Representations, since it creates a table of these kinds of attributes, but it is going about it backwards.  Most likely that would perform badly, since it would be custom symbols for every feature initially.

Comment: If/when implemented, I think this would be more likely to happen in ArcGIS Pro than ArcMap.